# How to randomly shuffle asyncio.Queue in Python?

Tags: queue, python-asyncio, shuffle

When I want to randomly shuffle a list in Python, I do:

```
from random import shuffle
shuffle(mylist)
```

How would I do the equivalent to an instance of [asyncio.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/asyncio-queue.html)? Do I have to convert the queue to a list, shuffle the list, and then put them back on the Queue? Or is there a way to do it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in `Queue` [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/asyncio/queues.py#L51), items in `Queue` are actually stored in `_queue` attribute. It can be used to extend `Queue` through inheritance:

```
import asyncio
from random import shuffle


class MyQueue(asyncio.Queue):
    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle(self._queue)


async def main():
    queue = MyQueue()    
    await queue.put(1)
    await queue.put(2)
    await queue.put(3)

    queue.shuffle()

    while not queue.empty():
        item = await queue.get()
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

---

If you want to shuffle existing `Queue` instance, you can do it directly:

```
queue = asyncio.Queue()
shuffle(queue._queue)
```

It's usually not a good solution for obvious reason, but on the other hand probability that `Queue`'s implementation will change in future in a way to make it problem seems relatively low (to me at least).